# Copy and Paste Values to remove formula

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question on here and I'm not very experienced with vba.
I have an Excel worksheet called Log with formulas in cells AK2:AQ500 that are capturing information.
When the document is saved, I would like to convert any non-blank cells in that range to values, whilst leaving the formulas in the cells that appear blank.
Can anybody give me some help?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got a solution that works for you. It would be helpful (both for others who are also searching for a solution and for those looking for unsolved questions) if you would mark the solution as accepted (there should be a checkmark to the left which can be clicked). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub fixat()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("AK2:AQ500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for such a quick reply.

That is very close to what I need.

I tried it, and it has removed the "blank" formulas and kept the formulas in the populated cells.

Just a little tweak and I think it'll be there.

Thanks again.